# Should I "think" all my data as streams when working with Observables?

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, observable

Say we retrieve an array of Category as a JSON :

```
[ {id: "111", name: "cat1"}, {id: "222", name: "cat2"}, {id: "333", name: "cat3"} ]
```

A method gets it :

```
getCategories(): Observable<Array<Category>> {
    return this.http.get('/categories').map(data => data.json());
}
```

We also have :

```
getCategoryById(id): Observable<Category> {
    return this.getCategories()
         .map(categories => categories.find(c => c.id === id));
}
```

This works, but I wonder if I am using observables the right way.
**Should I think my categories as a stream instead of an atomic bunch of data ?**

The code would be :

```
getCategoriesAsStream(): Observable<Category> {
    return this.http.get('/categories')
        .map(data => data.json())
        .flatMap(categories => Observable.from(categories));
}

getCategoryById(id): Observable<Category> {
    return this.getCategoriesAsStream()
        .find(category => category.id === id);
}
```

Since observables/RxProgramming seem to be the new way of thinking asynchronous operations, I feel that I should think everything as streams. But I also fear some pitfalls I would not see right now.

Have you any idea what would they be ?
Do you think it's overkill to re-think my data this way ?

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/media-p.slid.es/uploads/263775/images/1763829/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f4149696d5138432e6a7067.jpeg

Comment: The thing is that it really depends on the case.. There's no valid answer for this question I think... Normally, if I have a defined set of categories, I'd define their stream as a "group of objects", and each new notification in the stream would be a change on the whole set. But in other cases it makes more sense to keep the stream as individual objects, like events, notifications, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right. For me, Observables are "like streams", we can filter, squash them etc.

You need to remember one thing. When using observables with angular2, your second example could bring you some problems:

Imagine following template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let category from (getCategoriesAsStream() | async)">{{category}}</li>
</ul>
<!--- async pipe is preferable way to bind observables in template, ie they unsubscribe automatically ---->
```

given template would render only one element, instead three, which you got in json.

Concluding, `observables` should be treated as **streams of bunches**.